# Row wise Addition of one array to another

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, addition

I have one array A of 1x64 size and another array B of 64x1806 size. I want to add A into B in such a way that 1st element of A is added to 1st row of B and so on upto 64 element added to 64th row of B. how can I do this in matlab.?for example

```
A= (4 5 6 7) 
B=  (3 4 5;
    4 5 6;
    4 5 6;
    3 4 5 )
c=(4+3) (4+4) (4+5);
  (5+4) (5+5) (5+6);
  (6+4) (6+5) (6+6);...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you may want to use repmat first to "repeat" A for each column, and when it has the same size as B, just add B to it:

```
C = repmat(A', 1, size(B, 2)) + B
```

Comment: if I have 3 matrices `A=[1;
   2;
   3]
B=[2 3 4;
   5 6 7;
   8 9 0]
C=[3 4 5 6;
   9 8 7 6;
   5 4 2 1]` and I want to add them in this way                          D=`[(1+2+3) (1+2+4) (1+2+5) (1+2+6) (1+3+3) (1+3+4) (1+3+5) (1+3+6) (1+4+3) (1+4+4) (1+4+5) (1+4+6);
   (2+5+9) (2+5+8) (2+5+7) (2+5+6) (2+6+9) (2+6+8) (2+6+7) (2+6+6) (2+7+9) (2+7+8) (2+7+7) (2+7+6);
   (3+8+5) (3+8+4) (3+8+2) (3+8+1) (3+9+5) (3+9+4) (3+9+2) (3+9+1) (3+0+5) (3+0+4) (3+0+2) (3+0+1)]` then how can this be method be extended?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to add `A` transposed and `B` element-wise with singleton expansion:

```
A = [4 5 6 7]
B = [3 4 5; 4 5 6; 4 5 6; 3 4 5];
C = bsxfun(@plus, A.', B);
```

Or, from Matlab R2016b, you can use `+` directly, thanks to [implicit singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/):

```
C = A.' + B;
```